# How to implement nested if else and using SetState in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, if-statement, frontend

I have following code:

```
const Stepper = (id) => {
  let currId = id;
  const steps = [
    "Event Information",
    "Agenda & Schecule",
    "Budget Information",
    "Registration Attendee",
  ];
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);
  const [selectorCard, setSelectorCard] = useState(0);
  const [isStatus, setStatus] = useState("");
  const [complete, setComplete] = useState(false);

  const checkData = (id) => {
    if (id === "0") {
      setSelectorCard(0);
      setCurrentStep(1);
      () => setStatus("Pending");
    } else if (id === "1") {
      setSelectorCard(1);
      setCurrentStep(2);
      setStatus("Client Negotiation Approved");
    } else if (id === "2") {
      setSelectorCard(0);
      setCurrentStep(1);
      setStatus("Client Negotiation Rejected");
    } else if (id === "3") {
      setSelectorCard(2);
      setCurrentStep(3);
      setStatus("Agenda Schedule Approve");
    } else if (id === "4") {
      setSelectorCard(1);
      setCurrentStep(2);
      setStatus("Agenda Schedule Revision");
    } else if (id === "5") {
      setSelectorCard(3);
      setCurrentStep(4);
      setStatus("Event Budget Approved");
    } else if (id === "6") {
      setSelectorCard(2);
      setCurrentStep(3);
      setStatus("Event Budget Revision");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkData(currId.Id);
    console.log(currId.Id);
    console.log(isStatus);
  }, []);
```

When i try to look at console.log it always bring null value, just a few conditions bring the correct value of setStatus() function.
Please englight me about this.

I have search any reference about null value of setState

Comment: () => setStatus("Pending");
This is the function declaration, but it was not called.
Please update this as following.
setStatus("Pending");

Comment: hai @JasonMing i have updated it into this
const [isStatus, setStatus] = useState("Null");
  const [complete, setComplete] = useState(false);
  if (id == 0) {
    setSelectorCard(0);
    setCurrentStep(1);
    setStatus("Pending");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isStatus);
  }, []);
but still not change into pending

Comment: Generally, you should consider using a mapping of values when you start to see a long series of `if...else` like that ([example](https://tsplay.dev/WYlg3m)). You might also consider researching [enums in the TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) — using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) (raw numeric literals) can become difficult to reason about. (Be sure to read the last section about [objects vs enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)). Good luck in your programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that `currId` is empty when the component is initialized? If so, then the current approach is problematic, since you're trying to access `currId` in the `useEffect` without including it in the dependency array (so you have a stale closure).

You can add it as follows:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!currId.Id) { 
      return;
    }
    checkData(currId.Id);
    console.log(currId.Id);
    console.log(isStatus);
  }, [currId]);
```

This way every time `currId` changes, the `useEffect` will run updating state accordingly

Alternatively you can just put the id in the dep array:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ...// same as above
  }, [currId.Id]);
```

Which I'd say is probably the better approach if that's all you need to access in the `useEffect`, especially if `currId` is in fact an object with other potentially changing data

Comment: hi @DannyMoshe, thank you very much, for this one.
I have found another approach when setState and update it accordingly, i was found that setState is asynchronous so, i need to callback that setState to get updated value